# Zurb foundation 4 classes

Tags: zurb-foundation

Is there any documentation that explains each class in foundation.css? I am not great at front-end development and don't seem to be grasping the concepts with just cursory documentation available on zurb's site. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none. I think it will be tough for them, the ZURBlings, and overly-exhausting for us, to go over it, documented. I think what you need to know is what Responsive Design is all about. You can have a good beginner's introduction here:

- [From Wikipedia - a bird's eye
  view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)
- [Another bird's eye view of
  RD](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/)

Then continue on reading what [Foundation is basically about](http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.php).

And once you have a broader knowledge of what RD and Foundation is basically about, you can [go crazy about it here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/) and learn that it can actually allow you do more.

You really need to learn about their css once you are comfortable using Foundation, having read the links I gave you, and want to start to tweaking some of the configuration - which by the way is already explained in their docs.

Comment: That's a shame. In any case, given how far they help you with this framework, I cannot possibly crib about putting some effort from my side.

Comment: Can you let us know which specifically you want to understand? I mean which concept, in Foundation, are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sure. I am okay with the fundamentals. I know you have to add a row and then divide them up into columns. There are classes to add a row. There are classes to add columns. Image in a column is not the same as text in a column. They seem to behave differently when you resize the browser to test for responsiveness. So I am sometimes not sure if I am supposed to use a combination of classes or a different class altogether...I wish I could hit F1 on a class and read a description. I know what I am asking is not going to happen...I will take a look at the classes and check them out..

Comment: Yeah. Well the good thing is, you can always ask here when you hit a wall and be guaranteed that someone will help you out, in this great community ;)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no document that explains each and every class, but you can try to look at the kitchensink

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/kitchen-sink.html

They have (almost) every component available as a demo in a single page. So you could inspect each of these elements and familiarize  yourself with the class names.

This applies only to F4, I don't see a kitchen sink in F5

Comment: @VoronoiPotato Please check now